# Why my balance decrease while baking?

Tags: solo-baking

my tezos balance is decreasing while baking. anyone know why?
what is current deposit endorsement/baking?
does my balance =  current deposit endorsement/baking + current balance?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

when you bake and endorse your funds will get locked up as a deposit for an amount of time. then you will receive your baking/endorsement rewards and you'll receive your deposit back.